# How can I fix an AttributeError in my Python program when testing for valid and invalid bank transactions?

Tags: python, attributeerror

I've been stuck on this problem for a while and after searching for an answer applicable to my problem it doesnt end up working. I'm sort of new to python and need help. I'm trying to test for valid and invalid transactions from a bank program. I get:

AttributeError: 'Customer' object has no attribute 'CDeposit'

Here's the code.

```
from CAccount import CAccount
from SAccount import SAccount
from Customer import Customer

class Bank:

    @staticmethod
    def main():
        CSaindex = []
        cusindex = []
        idx = 0

        fr = open("C:\\Users\\danie\\Desktop\\work\\programming\\python profile\\CAccounts.txt", "r")

        for ln in fr:
             ln = ln.rstrip("\n")
             temp = ln.split(";")

             ca = CAccount(int(temp[0]), temp[1], temp[2], temp[3])
             CSaindex.append(ca)

        fr.close()

        fr = open("C:\\Users\\danie\\Desktop\\work\\programming\\python profile\\SAccounts.txt", "r")

        for ln in fr:
            ln = ln.rstrip("/n")
            temp = ln.split(";")

            sa = SAccount(int(temp[0]), temp[1], temp[2], temp[3])
            CSaindex.append(sa)

        fr.close()

        fr = open("C:\\Users\\danie\\Desktop\\work\\programming\\python profile\\Customers.txt", "r")

        for ln in fr:
            ln = ln.rstrip("/n")
            temp = ln.split(";")
            
            cus = Customer(int(temp[0]), temp[1], int(temp[2]), temp[3], CSaindex[idx]) 
            cusindex.append(cus)
            idx += 1
        fr.close()

        for ca in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]:
            print("-------------Checking Detials:---------------")
            print(CSaindex[ca])

        print()
        print()

        for sa in [8, 9 ,10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]:
            print("------------saving details:-------------")
            print(CSaindex[sa])

        print()
        print()

        
        for cs in cusindex:
            print("------------customer accounts:------------")
            print("customer: " + cs.getCustNm())
            print(cs.getAccObj())
        
        
        #--------------------CHECKING ACCOUNT TEST--------------
        cusindex[1].CDeposit(2000.00) #invalid deposit 
        cusindex[4].CWithdrawal(1100.00) #invalid withdrawal

        cusindex[3].CDeposit(450.00) #valid deposit
        cusindex[6].CWithdrawal(100.00) #valid withdrawal

        #----------------------SAVING ACCOUNT TEST---------------

        cusindex[8].SDeposit(2000.00)  #invalid deposit 
        cusindex[15].SWithdrawal(2500.00)  #invalid withdrawal

        cusindex[14].SDeposit(50.00)  #valid deposit
        cusindex[13].SWithdrawal(200.00) #valid withdrawal

        
        with open('BankingReceipt.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write('\n'.join(map(str,CSaindex)))
        

        

Bank.main()
```

heres the terminal:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\danie\Desktop\work\programming\python profile\Bank.py", line 118, in 
Bank.main()
File "c:\Users\danie\Desktop\work\programming\python profile\Bank.py", line 93, in main
cusindex[1].CDeposit(2000.00) #invalid deposit
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Customer' object has no attribute 'CDeposit'
PS C:\Users\danie\Desktop\work\programming\python profile>

heres CAccount, SAccount looks the same:

```
class CAccount:

    bsbNo = 1246
    
    def __init__(self, accNo, accType, bal, minAmt=50.00):
        self.__accNo = accNo
        self.__accType = accType
        self.__bal = bal
        self.__minAmt = minAmt


    def getAccNo(self):
        return self.__accNo
    def getAccType(self):
        return self.__accType
    def getBal(self):
        return self.__bal
    def getMinAmt(self):
        return self.__minAmt
    
    def CDeposit(self, deposit_amount):
        if deposit_amount < self.__minAmt:
            print(self.__accNo)
            print(deposit_amount)
            print(self.__minAmt)
            print("Deposit amount is less than minimum amount!")
        

        else:
            self.__bal = deposit_amount + self.__bal
            print(self.__accNo)
            print(deposit_amount)
            print(self.__bal)
            print("Deposit was successful!")
            
    def CWithdrawal(self, withdrawal_amount):
        if withdrawal_amount > self.__bal:
            print(self.__accNo)
            print(withdrawal_amount)
            print(self.__bal)
            print("Withdrawal amount is greater than balance")

        else:
            self.__bal = self.__bal - withdrawal_amount
            print(self.__accNo)
            print(withdrawal_amount)
            print(self.__bal)
            print("Withdrawal was successful!")



    def __str__(self):
        return " Account Number: " + str(self.__accNo) + " Account Type: " + self.__accType + " Balance: " + str(self.__bal) + " Minimum Amount: " + str(self.__minAmt) + " Branch Number: " + str(self.bsbNo)
```

Thanks in advance

I checked the indentation and other solutions but none seemed to work or applicable. I'm new to OOP so i appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

1. `AttributeError: 'Customer' object has no attribute 'CDeposit'`
   Valid Error as I see from the code that, `'CDeposit'` lies in `CAccount` Class
2. `cusindex = []` is an array. You are calling/invoking `CDeposit` method on an array `cusindex[1].CDeposit(2000.00) #invalid deposit`. Which cannot be done. As its not array method.